# unwind: Unknown symbol address (no kernel crash)

Tags: embedded-linux

I'm running linux (3.10.79) in an embedded application. Lately I get tons of

```
unwind: Unknown symbol address [some address]
unwind: Index not found [same address]
```

warnings.

I have seen that this log entry comes from [unwind.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/unwind.c) (line 406) but I am bit clueless which part of my system is causing that.

**Questions**

1. Whats unwind.c doing?
2. If the answer to question 1 doesn't already answer that: How do I find out which part of my system is causing that.

Comment: See [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/arm-kernel/msg609048.html) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, unwind.c provide stack unwinding support on arm Arch.

He will create unwind table, this table mainly give the data about call backtrace.
For information about the structure of the unwind tables, you can refer to "Exception Handling ABI for the ARM Architecture" at:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html

2, about the root cause of this error, I think in most probably, it have relation with the toolchain you used to build kernel, you can check your toolchain or change to a more stable one.